# Hibernate "org.hibernate.QueryException"

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hibernate throws such exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 2, actually detected 0
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:270)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1309)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1408)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
at pl.code.dao.PersonDAO.personExists(PersonDAO.java:59)
```

In this method:

```
@Override
public boolean personExists(String firstName, String location) {
    TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = ? and p.location = ?", Person.class);
    List<Person> all = query.getResultList();
    return all.size() > 0 ? true : false;

}
```

I'm using Hibernate version 5.2.9.Final. 
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Where are you specifying the parameters required by your query.  p.firstName = ? and p.location = ?",

Comment: Please you the below answer to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please use this as the below example to pass in your paramters

```
Query q =session.createQuery("select u from User u where u.location=? and u.id in (:user_ids)");
    q.setParameter(0, location);
    q.setParameterList("user_ids", userIds);
    return q.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I pass in parameters this way:

```
@Override
public synchronized boolean addPerson(Person person){
           if (personDAO.personExists(person.getFirstName(), person.getLocation())) {
               return false;
           } else {
               personDAO.addPerson(person);
               return true;
           }
}
```

and in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> addPerson(@RequestBody Person person, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    boolean flag = personService.addPerson(person);
           if (flag == false) {
          return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
           }
           HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
           headers.setLocation(builder.path("/person/{id}").buildAndExpand(person.getPid()).toUri());
           return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: but you still have to specify your parameters as per the below answer